# I have a column in Excel which gets data from another column, in another spreadsheet. How do I add an empty row after every cell?

Tags: excel, insert, row

As the title suggests, I have a column in my first worksheet which gets its data from another column, in a second spreadsheet.

I have linked them using `='Data'!B1`

Of course, if I drag the handle down, I get all the remaining data from the linked column, but I would like to have an empty row after each cell.

Like so: B1 has data, B2 is blank, B3 has data, B4 is blank, etc.

If some kind person out there could help me out, I would appreciate it very much. I have tried macros and looked this up in forums but can't seem to make this work with Data --> Sort.

Thank you! :)

Comment: If you fill in the one cell with a formula, then next blank, then the next with a formula, then blank, then select those 4 and drag down, doesn't that work??

Comment: Nope. Tried that and the result is wrong, it looks like this:

`Sheet1 B1 has the data from Sheet2 B1 - then - 
Sheet2 B1 is Blank - then - 
Sheet1 B3 has the data from Sheet2 B3 instead of B2`

Comment: Ok, so the problem isn't skipping the cells, it's making the cells have the right reference... I'll post a solution for you now...

Comment: I edited the second reference to actually be ='Sheet2!B2'
but as I dragged down the cells, Excel thought I just wanted every 2 cells :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you're asking for, the way I would do it would be using the `Offset` or `Indirect` function so I can control which cells to pull in from the other sheet.

Given your example, in Sheet1, I would have:

```
B1: =OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1,(ROW(B1)-1)/2,0)
B2: <blank>
B3: =OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1,(ROW(B3)-1)/2,0)
B4: <blank>
```

You can drag this down and it will give you alternating formula / blanks and pull the consecutive row from the other sheet.

As a quick explation, the function will always look at cell `B1` in your second sheet and offset it by `(Row()-1)/2` rows... So, in row 1, it would offset it by `(1-1)/2 = 0` rows, in row 3, it would offset it by `(3-1)/2 = 1` rows, etc.

Hope this makes sense and does the trick!!

Comment: This worked great :) One learns something new everyday. Thanks !